# How can <td> of a table count, along with the number I print it?

Tags: jquery, html, count, html-table

How can  of a table count, along with the number I print it?
I want something like this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="count"></td>
    <td>question1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="count"></td>
    <td>question2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

========>

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="count">1</td>
    <td>question1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="count">2</td>
    <td>question2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to do so.

Here is one example:

```js
$('.count').each(function(i) {
  debugger;
  $(this).html(i + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="count"></td>
    <td>question1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="count"></td>
    <td>question2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a CSS counter:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: tdCounter;
}

.count::before {
  counter-increment: tdCounter;
  content: counter(tdCounter);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="count"></td>
    <td>question1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="count"></td>
    <td>question2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice solution here with css only @Turnip :) you got my vote.